# Windows Remote desktop over ssh by putty

Tags: ssh, windows-7, rdp, putty

I know this topic may be duplicate, but i cannot find out the solution from old post.

Here is my situation

```
Work PC <> Firewall (port 3389 blocked) <> Internet <> Home Router <> Home PC
```

So i want to build up a ssh channel in home pc remote from work pc over ssh tunnel (port 443)

I have tired putty, bitvise ssh, freesshd but with no luck

what I have tired currently:

Assume:

- Home and Work OS : Windows 7
- Public IP of Home Router: 100.100.100.100
- Private IP of Home PC :192.168.1.199

Home PC :

- install bitvise ssh listening localhost on port 22, enable port forwarding
- create a test local account
- a Remote desktop account ready
- connect to bitvise ssh port 22 by putty use test account
- Router port forward 443 to 192.168.1.199:3391
- putty config : tunnel L3391 127.0.0.1:3389

Testing :

1. Open windows rdp,
2. connect to 127.0.0.1:3391,
3. login dialog prompt,
4. enter the remote desktop account -> rdp welcome screen pop up, ->
   Access is denied message displayed.

For the localhost testing already failure, so i have not try to test it from out side

Anyone knows how to make it happen, thanks

Comment: The fact that you are able to reach the "welcome" screen makes me think that everything is ok from a pure network point of view. Then "Access denied" seems more to be a local concern.

Comment: I'm not going to much help other than to say check event viewer on your home pc to make sure the connection is making it, it's authenticating, and also make sure you have remoting turned on and at a guess not using the newer authentication method. I don't have a pc in front of me so I can't give you the technical term, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Work computer has access to `home_router:443`? SSH necessarily need?

Possibly try without it:

1. Configure port forwarding on the router 443 on the 3389 home computer
2. Try RDP connect to `address_of_home_router:443`